# Embedding pygal in web2py

Tags: web2py, pygal

pygal, renders an svg and returns in the graphs dictionary. I try to embed it into a web2py page. That works. But I can't figure out how to reduce the size of the graphs on the page.

the view:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h1>Hello {{=request.vars.simulation_id}}</h1>
<figure> 
    {{=XML(one)}}
    {{=XML(two)}}
</figure>
```

and the default.py function:

```
def run_simulation():
    simulation = start.Simulation()
    graphs = simulation.run()
    return graphs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like pygal supports setting the size directly in the  code: http://pygal.org/web/#iddirectly-in-the-html

Alternatively you can override the width and height settings on the SVG element by using CSS:

```
.svg-container svg {
        height: 240px;
        width: 240px;
}
```

NOTE: I'm using a class selector on the assumption that you might want different sizes for different SVG images. If you want the same size for all images then you should be good with just `svg` in the CSS selector. Also worth mentioning that you have to override both height and width, if you just do one your SVG image won't resize.

Here is a complete example, using CSS embedded in the HTML file. It shows that you can use absolute scaling (fixed px values) as well as relative scaling.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- CSS embedded in HTML here. 
         For reusability you could put the CSS in a separate file 
         and link to it here instead 
    -->
    <style>
        /* Add svg-small class to an element to scale the child SVG element(s) to fixed width and height */
        .svg-small svg {
            height: 24px;
            width: 24px;
        }

        /* Add svg-halfwidth class to an element to scale the child SVG element(s) to half the page width
           The height will scale automatically to preserve the aspect ratio. */
        .svg-halfwidth svg {
            width: 50%;
            height: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<figure class="svg-small">
<caption>A small droid</caption>
<svg fill="#000000" height="240" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="240" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M6 18c0 .55.45 1 1 1h1v3.5c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5V19h2v3.5c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5V19h1c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V8H6v10zM3.5 8C2.67 8 2 8.67 2 9.5v7c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5S5 17.33 5 16.5v-7C5 8.67 4.33 8 3.5 8zm17 0c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5v7c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5v-7c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5zm-4.97-5.84l1.3-1.3c.2-.2.2-.51 0-.71-.2-.2-.51-.2-.71 0l-1.48 1.48C13.85 1.23 12.95 1 12 1c-.96 0-1.86.23-2.66.63L7.85.15c-.2-.2-.51-.2-.71 0-.2.2-.2.51 0 .71l1.31 1.31C6.97 3.26 6 5.01 6 7h12c0-1.99-.97-3.75-2.47-4.84zM10 5H9V4h1v1zm5 0h-1V4h1v1z"/>
</svg>
</figure>

<figure class="svg-halfwidth">
<caption>A scaled droid</caption>
<svg fill="#000000" height="240" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="240" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M6 18c0 .55.45 1 1 1h1v3.5c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5V19h2v3.5c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5V19h1c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V8H6v10zM3.5 8C2.67 8 2 8.67 2 9.5v7c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5S5 17.33 5 16.5v-7C5 8.67 4.33 8 3.5 8zm17 0c-.83 0-1.5.67-1.5 1.5v7c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5v-7c0-.83-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5zm-4.97-5.84l1.3-1.3c.2-.2.2-.51 0-.71-.2-.2-.51-.2-.71 0l-1.48 1.48C13.85 1.23 12.95 1 12 1c-.96 0-1.86.23-2.66.63L7.85.15c-.2-.2-.51-.2-.71 0-.2.2-.2.51 0 .71l1.31 1.31C6.97 3.26 6 5.01 6 7h12c0-1.99-.97-3.75-2.47-4.84zM10 5H9V4h1v1zm5 0h-1V4h1v1z"/>
</svg>
</figure>
</body>
</html>
```

Depending on how you are generating these files, it may be easier to do embedded CSS as shown above, but in general I would separate my CSS into a separate file:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
<head>
<body> ... as before ... </body>
</html>
```

Then `styles.css` is just the same content as the `<style>` tag in the previous example:

```
.svg-small svg {
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
}

.svg-halfwidth svg {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that {{=XML(one)}} renders everything ven <svg> to </svg>, so I cant add whidth or hight=80% without any problems.

Comment: Hey Davoud, I was actually working with some similar issues today and found that I could do what I needed using CSS. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Could you expand a bit, where does the CSS go in a separate file? Can it be done for every svg graph on the page seperately?

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer above. Yes it can be applied to each graph on the page separately, just add the appropriate CSS class to each wrapper (figure or div or whatever) element you have around the SVG. You can use different classes for different scaling effects as shown in the example.